# Trouble Installing Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Intel RST...)

Tags: intel, 20.04, rst

I'm a long time lurker; first time poster.

I just purchased a Dell Precision 7730 laptop with an Intel Core i7-8850H processor and PC601 NVMe SK hynix 512 GB SSD. The BIOS version is Dell Inc 1.12.1, 11/11/1/2019, which appears to be the most current version, and the BIOS mode is UEFI. The laptop also came with Windows 10 Professional (64-bit) factory installed.

When I first went to install Ubuntu as my new primary OS, Ubuntu brought up a message saying this laptop has Intel's RST, and that it first needs to be disabled. Based on a lot of the feedback from the Ubuntu community, I've made sure the boot menu has the following options enabled or disabled:

*Enable Legacy Option ROMS (unchecked)
*Enable Attempt Legacy Boot (unchecked - ghosted)
*SATA Operation AHCI (checked)
*Secure Boot Enable (unchecked)

Now when I go into the boot menu, though, and select my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS amd64 ISO (on a removable flash drive) created with Rufus, the screen will go black. I've waited for ten minutes, hoping this might be related to a longer boot time experienced going from "Raid On" to "AHCI" but that doesn't appear to be the case. It just appears to freeze. (Note: I can still get into my windows desktop just fine, after I restart the machine.)

So, Is there a way to install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS onto this computer? Is there something I'm missing?

And if it's any help at all, I'm 100% behind nuking Windows 10 and going exclusively to Ubuntu! There is zero information on this disk I want to preserve. It's more important to get this laptop to Ubuntu, permanently.

Thank you all for the help.
//Mike

Comment: This really sucks. I have spent the last week working with a PC repair shop in my neighborhood, and we're closer, but still not there yet. We have the legacy boot options enabled, AHCI enabled, secure boot disabled... we've uninstalled Windows completely, and managed to get Ubuntu installed. (There are probably more things my guy has done without explaining it to me in detail.) HOWEVER, after rebooting the machine a couple times, the PC stalls in start-up. Like the motherboard firmware reconfigures a setting behind closed doors, which trips up Ubuntu, and I'm left with a $1,600 paper weight.

Comment: Did you try installing 18.04 LTS? it may be worth isolating the Ubuntu OS version, to determine whether the problem is hardware (incompatibility or even damaged as new) vs the specific operating system incompatibility. (Specifically as 20.04 is so new.)

Comment: We have tried installing 18 as well as 16. And the PC will not boot with any reliability.It might reboot once, and then freeze up (at restart). It might reboot five times, and then freeze up (at restart). It's odd.

Comment: I have some general recommendations to pinpoint the problem. **Use some way to determine the former boot progress (event logs) to identify the point of failure; determine which stage of boot is failing.** Remove non essential accessories/devices (xtra usb, screens). Contact Dell, determine if they provide support for any linux distribution. Boot to the "safe mode" form of Ubuntu, isolate (enable 1-by-1) the device that is causing the problem.